# Magento tax amount randomly showing zero on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

In my Magento store tax price not working on some states, on California taxt is being calculated but on new York and on many more states is's showing 0 price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my solution, may be it will help 
I have migrated my database from demo to live,thus i got this problem i have check tax tables and found what's the problem.
There should be more than 41346 records in. 
 **tax_calculation_rate** table.
Now check this data here:-
**Sale->tax-> Manage tax zone & rates** 
And now check your all records they should be same as in tax_calculation_rate  records. 
If they are not same then delete all tax tables and again import all tables problem will be solved.Again check all records.

Answer (score -1):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax, and check 'Default Tax Destination Calculation' tab.

Comment: in this section what have to do ?

Comment: Check 'Default State' and 'Default Post Code' values.

Comment: They are already configured

Comment: For store view configuration scope too?

Comment: Yes, same setting is working on my dev server but it's not working on my live server